# intersection list add i+1 in i vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Code:

```
  Dim intersectionList As New List(Of String)()
        Dim lines() As String = TxtMReadOnly2.Lines
        For i As Integer = 1 To lines.Length - 2
            Dim firstBoxList = TxtMReadOnly2.Lines(i).Split(",")
            Dim secondBoxList = TxtMReadOnly2.Lines(i + 1).Split(",")
            intersectionList.Add(String.Join(",", secondBoxList.Intersect(firstBoxList)))
        Next
        TextBox3.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, intersectionList)
```

Input:

```
7,11,13,20,21,22,25,30,40,43,50,53,57,64,67,68,70,71,78,79
1,10
1,11,16,17,21,28,30,34,37,40,45,48,53,57,62,67,68,75,76,79
4,12
4,13,20,21,24,26,30,31,33,36,40,42,44,52,53,54,68,69,70,77
2,7
2,8,10,12,30,35,40,44,45,48,49,56,57,60,61,63,69,70,75,78
7,11
```

Expected Output: [image]

> 1,10 > intersection with > 7,11,13,20,21,22,25,30,40,43,50,53,57,64,67,68,70,71,78,79 > value nothing (no intersection)
>
> 4 12 > intersection with > 1,11,16,17,21,28,30,34,37,40,45,48,53,57,62,67,68,75,76,79 > value nothing (no intersection)
>
> 2,7 > intersection with > 4,13,20,21,24,26,30,31,33,36,40,42,44,52,53,54,68,69,70,77 > value nothing (no intersection)
>
> 7,11 > intersection with > 2,8,10,12,30,35,40,44,45,48,49,56,57,60,61,63,69,70,75,78 > value nothing (no intersection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the current result because you compare the first line with the second, the second with the third, the third with the fourth and so on when you are meant to compare the first with the second and the third with the fourth, etc.

You need to use the `Step` statement in order to loop in two's.  Like this:

```
Dim intersectionList As New List(Of String)()
Dim lines() As String = TxtMReadOnly2.Lines
For i As Integer = 1 To lines.Length - 2 Step 2 'Add this 
    Dim firstBoxList = TxtMReadOnly2.Lines(i).Split(",")
    Dim secondBoxList = TxtMReadOnly2.Lines(i + 1).Split(",")
    intersectionList.Add(String.Join(",", secondBoxList.Intersect(firstBoxList)))
Next
TextBox3.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, intersectionList)
```

Comment: I think it worked. indeed it was, I had to do this and I didn't know how but it was quickly resolved.